# SQL Query to replace multiple values in template from many-to-many table

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, many-to-many

I want to translate a template in an sql query. Lets assume there are the following fourtables: state, stateProperty, state_stateproperty and translation:

**state_stateproperty**

```
|---------------------|--------------------|
|      state_id       | stateproperties_id |
|---------------------|--------------------|
|          1          |        2           |
|---------------------|--------------------|
|          1          |        3           |
|---------------------|--------------------|
```

**stateproperty**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|  id  |     key      |      value       |
|------|--------------|------------------|
|  2   | ${firstName} |      John        |
|------|--------------|------------------|
|  3   | ${lastName}  |      Doe         |
|------|--------------|------------------|
```

**state**

```
|---------------------|
|  id  |  template    |
|------|--------------|
|  1   |  template    |
|------|--------------|
```

**translation**

```
|------------|--------------|---------------------------------|
|  language  |  messageId   |             value               |
|------------|--------------|---------------------------------|
|  en        |  template    | ${lastName}, ${firstName} alarm |
|------------|--------------|---------------------------------|
```

The aim is to get a new entity named translatedstate that includes the translated template of the state. In this example the translated template would look like: "Doe, John alarm". How can you join a many to many table in native sql and translate the template of the state with the values of its related state properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I would create a little function where I would loop through your `state_property` and cumulative replace the found wildcard string with its text.

---

But I had some fun to solve it in a query. I am not sure if it matches all special cases but for your example it works:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=10a76055d256199b3916e6c030ddf82b)

```
SELECT
    string_agg(                                                           -- 8
        regexp_replace(split_key, '^.*\}', value),                        -- 7
        '' ORDER BY row_number
    )
FROM (
    SELECT
        s.id,
        sp.value,
        substring(key, 3) as s_key,                                       -- 5
        split_table.*
    FROM translation t
    JOIN statechange sc ON t.messageid = sc.completemessagetemplateid     -- 1
    JOIN state s ON s.id = sc.state_id
    JOIN state_stateproperty ssp ON s.id = ssp.state_id
    JOIN stateproperty sp ON ssp.stateproperties_id = sp.id
    JOIN translation stnme ON s.nameid = stnme.messageid
    CROSS JOIN                                        
        regexp_split_to_table(                                            -- 3   
            -- 2
            replace(t.messagetranslation, '${state}', stnme.messagetranslation),
            '\$\{'
        ) WITH ORDINALITY as split_table(split_key, row_number)           -- 4
    WHERE t.language = 'en'
) s
WHERE position(s_key in split_key) = 0 and split_key != ''                -- 6
GROUP BY id                                                               -- 8
```

1. Simple join the tables together (for next time you could simplify your example a little bit so that we don't have to create these different table. I am sure you know how to join)
2. Hardly replace the `${state}` variable with the state `nameid`
3. This splits the template string every time a `${` string is found. So it creates a new row which begins a certain wildcard. Note that `${firstName}` would become `firstName}` because the string delimiter is being deleted.
4. Adding a row count to get a criteria how the rows are ordered when I aggregate them later (8). [`WITH ORDINALITY`](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-with-ordinality/) only works as part of the  `FROM` clause so the whole function it has been added here with a join.
5. Because of (3) I strip the `${` part from the keys as well. So it can be better parsed and compared later (in 6)
6. Because (3) creates too much rows (cross join) I want only these where the `key` is the first wildcard of my split string. All others are wrong.
7. Now I replace the wildcard with this key
8. Because we have only one wildcard per row we need to merge them together into one string again (grouped by `state_id`). The achieve the right order, we are using the row number from (5)

Comment: @unrated did this help? If so please do not forget to upvote (it honors the work the author did for you with some internal credibility). If it does not only helps but is fully correct you should accept. this shows other that they do not need to do any work because your problem is solved.

Comment: Since my query is much bigger i tried to integrate your query into mine. But until now i couldnt make it work.
ERROR:  column t.value does not exist
LINE 22:    regexp_split_to_table(t.value, '\$\{') as split_key,
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "sp.value".

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is the problem: There is no column for alias t. In my example t is for the table translation. Maybe you have another alias for it?

Comment: I understand the error message but I just copied your exact query into mine. Maybe i should update my post and add my complete query.

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=8a77a390183008da9a130b650e354955) Made it work at least. But the result is not as expected. There is a constant word ${state} that i want to replace always with the states name and the state properties are not replaced correctly when i have multiple stateproperties for different states. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: 1. in your question there is no state variable. So it never was taken. 2. Your example contains only one data set not several. With only one data set a GROUP BY wasn't necessary. I fixed my version and changed the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there is still something wrong when i swap ${lastName} with ${firstName} in the template. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d617f5366446f0440cea6c68e4174d7c)

Comment: Ah I see. It was my fault. Used the row_number() function before the expansion through the table. So after expand all elements got the same row number and so the aggregating comes in a random order. Now, to avoid a subquery, I used the WITH ORDINALITY functionality (I think the first time ever :D) to create the row numbers. Looks good now.

Comment: Thanks again. One last question. What did i do wrong [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e7757d09e88ac6ff3d61ba0ca569f86e) :)

Comment: There seems to be a joining problem if you add the table directly as column. This creates a cross join and (without complete debugging) something becomes unordered. If you do it in the subquery as I did: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=737c13d3f994ca08f57f4fe4d01e70e5 it should work. Maybe you have to add some more data to the group if you want to show them :)

Comment: may you have time to join the chat